# Inverse Laplace Transform of $\frac{s-3}{s[(s-3)^2+9]}$

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I am having problems solving this inverse Laplace transform:

ℒ$^{-1}\Large [\frac{s-3}{s[(s-3)^2+9]}]$

I did partial fraction decomposition, but ended up with complex expressions in some denominators, and I have no idea what do do from here or if this is even how to "solve" it.

Could anyone give me some helpful hints or references? I would appreciate it a lot!

Edit:

My problem is, specifically, finding the inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{s^2-6s+18}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to exploit some properties of the (inverse) Laplace transform. In particular:
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{f(s)}{s}\right) = \int_{0}^{t}\left(\mathcal{L}^{-1} f\right)(u)\,du,\tag{1} $$
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1} g'(s) = -t\cdot \left(\mathcal{L}^{-1} g\right)(t). \tag{2}$$
Since:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s-3}{(s-3)^2+9}\right)=e^{3t}\cos(3t), \tag{3} $$
by $(1)$ we simply have:
$$ \mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s-3}{s\left((s-3)^2+9\right)}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{1}{6}\left(-1+e^{3t}\left(\sin(3t)+\cos(3 t)\right)\right)}. \tag{4} $$

Comment: Thank you, but I really want to solve this "from the bottom". I am having problems solving the inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{s^2-6s+18}$, which has complex roots. How would you go about to solve this?

Comment: @Akitirija: it is way easier to go in the opposite direction and compute the Laplace transform of $\cos(kt)$ and $e^{kt}\cos(kt)$ by integration by parts.

Answer (score 1):

Note $\dfrac{s-3}{s\left[(s-3)^2+9\right]}$ can be expressed as

\begin{align*}
\frac{s-3}{s\left[(s-3)^2+9\right]}&=\frac{s-3}{s(s^2-6s+18)}\\
&=\frac{A}{s}+\frac{Bs+C}{s^2-6s+18}
\end{align*}

For some real numbers $A$, $B$ and $C$, that means
\begin{align*}
s-3&=A(s^2-6s+18)+(Bs+C)s\\
&=(A+B)s^2+(-6A+C)s+18A\\
\end{align*}
$$\iff \left\{\begin{matrix}A+B&=0\\-6A+C&=1\\18A&=-3\end{matrix}\right.$$

Then $A=-\frac{1}{6}$, $B=\frac{1}{6}$ and $C=0$.

Comment: Thank you, Mario. However, this still leaves me with the problem of solving the inverse Laplace of $\frac{1}{s^2-6s+18}$.

Comment: @Akitirija Shift Theorem

Comment: Thank you, McCarthy! I managed to use the first shift theorem to obtain Jack D'Aurizio's result.